# Spark 1.6: How to process extremely big DataFrame without for loop?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, dataframe, partitioning

I have a Hive table and i created an extremely big spark dataframe of the following shape:

```
------------------------------------------------------
|  Category  |Subcategory | Purchase_ID | Product_ID |
|------------+------------+-------------+------------|
| a          | a_1        | purchase 1  | product 1  |
| a          | a_1        | purchase 1  | product 2  |
| a          | a_1        | purchase 1  | product 3  |
| a          | a_1        | purchase 4  | product 1  |
| a          | a_2        | purchase 5  | product 4  |
| b          | b_1        | purchase 6  | product 5  |
| b          | b_2        | purchase 7  | product 6  |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Please note that this matrix is extremely big, tens of millions of purchases for each subcategories and 50M+ purchases for each category.

**My tasks are as following:**

- Group all purchases by 'subcategory' and compute cosine similarity between all products (means, if 2 products are found in all purchases together then their cosine similarity is 1.0, if they never appear together their cosine similarity is 0.0)
- Group all purchases by 'category' and compute cosine similarity between all products

**My current solution so far:**

First i collect all unique 'Subcategory' values into a driver machine from Hive using SQL and then i loop through each subcategory where i load data again for that particular subcategory and compute cosine similarity. Computing cosine similarity for each pair of products requires building NxN matrix. I thought (please correct me if i am wrong) that loading entire dataframe and groupby by Subcategory and computing NxN matrix for each subcategory might lead to out of memory error so i computed sequentially as following:

```
val subcategories = hiveContext.sql(s"SELECT Subcategory FROM $table_name")
val subcategory_ids = subcategories.select("Subcategory").collect()


// for each context, sequentially compute models
for ((arr_subcategory_id, index) <- subcategory_ids.zipWithIndex) {
    println("Loading current context")
    val subcategory_id = arr_subcategory_id(0)

    println("subcategory id: ".concat(subcategory_id.toString))
    val context_data = hiveContext.sql(s"SELECT Purchase_ID, Product_ID FROM $table_name WHERE Subcategory = $subcategory_id")       

    //UDF to concatenate column values into single long string
    class ConcatenatedGroupItems() extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

        // Input Data Type Schema
        def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(Array(StructField("item", StringType)))

        // Intermediate Schema
        def bufferSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("items", StringType)))

        // Returned Data Type .
        def dataType: DataType = StringType

        // Self-explaining
        def deterministic = true

        // This function is called whenever key changes
        def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) = {
            buffer(0) = "" // initialize to empty string
        }

        // Iterate over each entry of a group
        def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row) = {
            var tempString:String = buffer.getString(0)
            // add space in between the items unless it is the first element
            if (tempString.length() != 0){
                tempString = tempString + " "
            }

            buffer(0) = tempString.concat(input.getString(0))
        }

        // Merge two partial aggregates
        def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row) = {
            var tempString = buffer1.getString(0)
            // add space in between the items unless it is the first element
            if (tempString.length() != 0){
                tempString = tempString + " "
            }
            buffer1(0) = tempString.concat(buffer2.getString(0))
        }

        // Called after all the entries are exhausted.
        def evaluate(buffer: Row) = {
            buffer.getString(0)
        }
    }

    // ========================================================================================
    println("Concatenating grouped items")
    val itemConcatenator = new ConcatenatedGroupItems()
    val sents = context_data.groupBy("Purchase_ID").agg(itemConcatenator(context_data.col("Product_ID ")).as("items"))


    // ========================================================================================
    println("Tokenizing purchase items")
    val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("items").setOutputCol("words")
    val tokenized = tokenizer.transform(sents)


    // ========================================================================================
    // fit a CountVectorizerModel from the corpus
    println("Creating sparse incidence matrix")
    val cvModel: CountVectorizerModel = new CountVectorizer().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("features").fit(tokenized)
    val incidence = cvModel.transform(tokenized)


    // ========================================================================================
    // create dataframe of mapping from indices into the item id
    println("Creating vocabulary")
    val vocabulary_rdd = sc.parallelize(cvModel.vocabulary)
    val rows_vocabulary_rdd = vocabulary_rdd.zipWithIndex.map{ case (s,i) => Row(s,i)}
    val vocabulary_field1 = StructField("Product_ID", StringType, true)
    val vocabulary_field2 = StructField("Product_Index", LongType, true)
    val schema_vocabulary = StructType(Seq(vocabulary_field1, vocabulary_field2))
    val df_vocabulary = hiveContext.createDataFrame(rows_vocabulary_rdd, schema_vocabulary)


    // ========================================================================================
    println("Computing similarity matrix")
    val myvectors = incidence.select("features").rdd.map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[Vector])
    val mat: RowMatrix = new RowMatrix(myvectors)
    val sims = mat.columnSimilarities(0.0)


    // ========================================================================================
    // Convert records of the Matrix Entry RDD into Rows
    println("Extracting paired similarities")
    val rowRdd = sims.entries.map{case MatrixEntry(i, j, v) => Row(i, j, v)}


    // ========================================================================================
    // create dataframe schema
    println("Creating similarity dataframe")
    val field1 = StructField("Product_Index", LongType, true)
    val field2 = StructField("Neighbor_Index", LongType, true)
    var field3 = StructField("Similarity_Score", DoubleType, true)
    val schema_similarities = StructType(Seq(field1, field2, field3))

    // create the dataframe
    val df_similarities = hiveContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd, schema_similarities)


    // ========================================================================================
    println("Register vocabulary and correlations as spark temp tables")
    df_vocabulary.registerTempTable("df_vocabulary")
    df_similarities.registerTempTable("df_similarities")


    // ========================================================================================
    println("Extracting Product_ID")
    val temp_corrs = hiveContext.sql(
        "SELECT T1.Product_ID, T2.Neighbor_ID, T1.Similarity_Score " +
        "FROM " +
            "(SELECT Product_ID, Neighbor_Index, Similarity_Score " +
            "FROM df_similarities LEFT JOIN  df_vocabulary " +
            "WHERE df_similarities.Product_Index = df_vocabulary.Product_Index) AS T1 " +
        "LEFT JOIN " +
            "(SELECT Product_ID AS Neighbor_ID, Product_Index as Neighbor_Index FROM df_vocabulary) AS T2 " +
        "ON " +
            "T1.Neighbor_Index = T2.Neighbor_Index")


    // ========================================================================================
    val context_corrs = temp_corrs.withColumn("Context_ID", lit(context_id))


    // ========================================================================================
    context_corrs.registerTempTable("my_temp_table_correlations")
    hiveContext.sql(s"INSERT INTO TABLE $table_name_correlations SELECT * FROM my_temp_table_correlations")        
    // ========================================================================================
    // clean up environment
    println("Cleaning up temp tables")
    hiveContext.dropTempTable("my_temp_table_correlations")
    hiveContext.dropTempTable("df_similarities")
    hiveContext.dropTempTable("df_vocabulary")
}
```

}

**Problems:**

- this is extremely slow. Computing for each subcategory takes about 1 minute
- after processing of ~30 subcategories, i am getting out of memory errors.

**What is the right logic to solve such a problem?**

I could partition the dataframe by subcategory first then apply groupby according to subcategory and compute similarity for each subcategory but then if dataset is too big for that partition, i might get OOM when i build NxN matrix.